# curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination(WINDOWS)

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pip

I need to download get-pip.py on windows and this error appears(title). I need this file for pip ,because even if i installed the latest version of python pip still doesn't come with it or i can't anyway use it : it is not recognized error .I know I could just install PyCharm but it works slow on my computer and I am poor .Recommend another compiler which also has the download modules feature but is more lite?

(new to stack over flow because I have to write something here)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] detailing what you did and what you saw (as text) in return? As a new user here, also make sure you take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.